# Ruby memory (allocations) spikes when handling base64 strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a rails instance which on average uses about 250MB of memory. Lately I'm having issues with some really heavy spikes of memory usage which results in a response time of about ~25s. I have an endpoint which takes some relative simple params and base64 strings which are being send over to AWS.

See the image below for the correlation between memory/response time.[image]

Now, when I look at some extra logs what's specifically happening during that time, I found something interesting.[image]

First of all, I find the net_http memory allocations extremely high. Secondly, the update operation took about 25 sec in total. When I closely look at the timeline, I noticed some "blank gaps", between ~5 and ~15 seconds. The specific operations that are being done during those HTTP calls is from my perspective nothing special. But I'm a bit confused why those gaps occur, maybe someone could tell me a bit about that?

[image]

The code that's handling the requests:

```
def store_documents
        identity_documents.each do |side, content|
          is_file = content.is_a?(ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile)

          file_extension = is_file ? content : content[:name]
          file_name = "#{SecureRandom.uuid}_#{side}#{File.extname(file_extension)}"

          if is_file
            write_to_storage_service(file_name, content.tempfile.path)
          else
            write_file(file_name, content[:uri])
            write_to_storage_service(file_name, file_name)
            delete_file(file_name)
          end

          store_object_key_on_profile(side, file_name)
        end
      end
      # rubocop:enable Metrics/MethodLength

      def write_file(file_name, base_64_string)
        File.open(file_name, 'wb') do |f|
          f.write(
            Base64.decode64(
              get_content(base_64_string)
            )
          )
        end
      end

      def delete_file(file_name)
        File.delete(file_name)
      end

      def write_to_storage_service(file_name, path)
        S3_IDENTITY_BUCKET
          .object(file_name)
          .upload_file(path)
      rescue Aws::Xml::Parser::ParsingError => e
        log_error(e)
        add_errors(base: e)
      end

      def get_content(base_64_string)
        base_64_string.sub %r{data:((image|application)/.{3,}),}, ''
      end

      def store_object_key_on_profile(side, file_name)
        profile.update("#{side}_identity_document_object_key": file_name)
      end

      def identity_documents
        {
          front: front_identity_document,
          back:  back_identity_document
        }
      end

      def front_identity_document
        @front_identity_document ||= identity_check_params[:front_identity_document]
      end

      def back_identity_document
        @back_identity_document ||= identity_check_params[:back_identity_document]
      end
```

I tend towards some issues with Ruby GC, or perhaps Ruby doesn't have enough pages available to directly store the base64 string in memory? I know that Ruby 2.6 and Ruby 2.7 had some large improvements regarding memory fragmentation, but that didn't change much either (currently running Ruby 2.7.1)

I have my Heroku resources configured to use Standard-2x dynos (1GB ram) x3. `WEB_CONCURRENCY`(workers) is set to 2, and amount of threads is set to 5.

I understand that my questions are rather broad, I'm more interested in some tooling, or ideas that could help to narrow my scope. Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything that limits the size of the uploaded images? Is it just getting stuck occasionally processing synchronous file writes when too many people upload too many hi-res images at the same time? As Base64-encoded data is ~30% bigger than the original file...

Comment: @nullTerminator I know about the 30% increase. The images are on average a few MB, the highest one is 8MB, most of them are quite lower.